Sheet to edit data
I'm quite new to SwiftUI.
I have a view where I'd like to open a sheet to edit data in a List.
Here below the code of the view:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @Query(sort: \Stagione.idStagione) private var usoStagione: [Stagione]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @State private var stagione =  String(Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date()))
    @State private var miaSquadra = ""
    @State private var categoria = ""
    @State private var selStagione = Set<Stagione>()
    @State private var modificaStagione = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            GroupBox("Stagione") {
                Form {
                    TextField("Stagione:", text: $stagione)
                        .frame(width: 150)
                    TextField("Categoria:", text: $categoria)
                        .frame(width: 400)
                    TextField("Mia squadra:", text: $miaSquadra)
                        .frame(width: 400)
                    Button("Salva") {
                        let nuovaStagione = Stagione(idStagione: stagione, categoriaStagione: categoria, miaSquadra: miaSquadra)
                        context.insert(nuovaStagione)
                        miaSquadra = ""
                        categoria = ""
                        stagione = String(Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date()))
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .disabled(categoria.isEmpty || miaSquadra.isEmpty)
                }
                List(selection: $selStagione) {
                    ForEach(usoStagione, id: \.self) { stag in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("\(stag.idStagione)").font(.title2)
                            Text("\(stag.miaSquadra)").foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                            Text("\(stag.categoriaStagione)").foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        }
                    }
                    .contextMenu() {
                            Button(action: {
                                selStagione.forEach(context.delete)
                            }) {
                                Text("Cancella")
                            }
                        Button(action: {
                            self.modificaStagione = true
                        }) {
                            Text("Modifica")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $modificaStagione) {
                    ModificaStagione(stagione: Stagione)
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .padding()
            }

        }
        .padding()
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .navigationTitle("Impostazioni")
        GroupBox("Squadre") {
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SettingsView()
        .environmentObject(NavigationStateManager())
        .modelContainer(for: Stagione.self, inMemory: true)
}

While here below the code of the view ModificaStagione:
import SwiftUI

struct ModificaStagione: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    let stagione: Stagione
    @State private var idStagione = ""
    @State private var categoria = ""
    @State private var miaSquadra = ""
    @State private var vistaPrecedente = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            GroupBox {
                LabeledContent {
                    TextField("", text: $categoria)
                        .frame(width: 400)
                } label: {
                    Text("Categoria:")
                }
                LabeledContent {
                    TextField("", text: $miaSquadra)
                        .frame(width: 400)
                } label: {
                    Text("Mia squadra:")
                }
                if modifica {
                    Button("Aggiorna dati") {
                        stagione.idStagione = idStagione
                        stagione.categoriaStagione = categoria
                        stagione.miaSquadra = miaSquadra
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .navigationTitle("Modifica dati stagione")
        }
        .onAppear {
            idStagione = stagione.idStagione
            categoria = stagione.categoriaStagione
            miaSquadra = stagione.miaSquadra
        }
    }
    
    var modifica: Bool {
        categoria != stagione.categoriaStagione
        || miaSquadra != stagione.miaSquadra
    }
}

In the "Setting" view I receive an error message when I call the view "Modifica Stagione "saying that "Cannot convert value of type 'Stagione.Type' to expected argument type 'Stagione'".
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance,
A.

Typo.
As the error tells you Stagione is a type, not a variable.
So in your ModificaStagione(stagione: Stagione) you are trying to
pass a type to your ModificaStagione which is not correct.
It expects a variable of type Stagione in let stagione: Stagione
Try something like : ModificaStagione(stagione: stagione) if that is what
you are trying to do.

Uppercase Stagione is a type, lowercase stagione is a value. You need the value

Dears, what I'm trying is to select a row in the list, showing a "Modifica" button in the context menu and then show a sheet where I pass the values of the selected row in the list and then modify "categoria" and "miaSquadra" fields. Now, I have changed the "Stagione" parameter into "stagione", but I still get the following error: "Cannot find 'stagione' in scope". Please help me as I'm getting crazy....sorry for this....

Note in SettingsView, you declare @State private var stagione =  String(...)
but in ModificaStagione you have let stagione: Stagione, unless Stagione is an alias for String 
this is not going to work. In any case, try using  .sheet(item: ...), look it up for how to use it.

You could use selStagione if it wasn’t a Set, do you really need to have multiple selections for your list?

Hi @JoakimDanielson, no I need a single selection. How can I change the code so that it works with selStagione?

Don’t declare selStagion as a set and pass it to the sheet by using .sheet(item:) instead.
